# Checkout fr Woocommerce - load default WooCommerce checkout template on the fly

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have this scenario:
By default, checkout page is handled by Checkout for WooCommerce plugin, but I need to prevent plugin's template from loading, and load default WooCommerce checkout template if a certain $_GET parameter is provided.

I'm looking in plugin's filters and hooks but can't really find anything helpful.

Can anyone help with a hint please?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, found an undocumented hook - **cfw_load_checkout_template**

Example usage:

```
add_action('cfw_load_checkout_template', 'sd_handle_cfw_should_load');

    function sd_handle_cfw_should_load($value)
    {
        if(isset($_GET['sdc_modal'])) {
            return false;
        }

        return $value;
    }
```